# serial device output looks fine in gnu screen but garbled using cat

Tags: gnu-screen, cat, serial-port, serial-console

I have a serial device (Omega RDXL4SD thermocouple reader, comms details p 22 [here](https://www.omega.com/Manuals/manualpdf/M4963.pdf)) connected to a USB port on my Raspberry Pi running Raspbian via an FTDI cable. It appears at /dev/ttyUSB0 and the output looks perfect if I display it by calling

`pi@raspberrypi:~ $ screen /dev/ttyUSB0 9600`

The output is a few numbers. Each time it spits out a line, the cursor returns to the beginning of the line and overwrites it, so that there is only ever one line of numbers on the screen at a time.

Now, I want to use `cat`, not `screen` to achieve the same effect, but when I do I get boxes with question marks in them:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /dev/ttyUSB0
4401010000
```

I presume this is some kind of encoding problem. Can you explain what might be different about how these characters are being interpreted in `screen` versus `cat`, or suggest other troubleshooting steps?

In case it helps:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.9.41-v7+ #1023 SMP Tue Aug 8 16:00:15 BST 2017 armv7l 
GNU/Linux

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0
speed 9600 baud; line = 0;
min = 100; time = 2;
-icrnl -imaxbel
-opost -onlcr
-isig -icanon -echo
```

Edit: @meuh suggested adding -vet to display special characters. Now that I know about those flags, my particular problem is effectively solved! I still wouldn't mind an explanation of exactly what's going on here though.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat -vet /dev/ttyUSB0
^M^B4201010000^X^X^X^X^M^B4301010000^X^X^X^X^M^B4401010000^X^X^X^X^M^B41010100000245^M^B4201010000^X^X^X^X^M^B4301010000^X^X^X^X^M^B4401010000^X^X^X^X^M^B41010100000245^M^B4201010000^X^X^X^X^M^B4301010000^X^X^X^X^M^B4401010000^X^X^X^X^M^B41010100000245^M^B4201010000
```

Comment: Try `cat -vet /dev/ttyUSB0` to see the special characters. Add the output to your post.

Comment: Are you sure the characters aren't part of the protocol the device is using? I find it unlikely that something else is inserting them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the ^X characters, which are bytes of 0x18, are a sort of undocumented NaN in this protocol. There are multiple thermocouple ports, and if you only plug in one thermocouple you get one line with a temperature value and then a bunch of lines ending with ^X.

For some reason, cat in my terminal displays these characters as boxes but screen doesn't display them at all.